# Regex for namespaced Ruby class / module names

Tags: ruby, regex

What is a good regex to match any namespaced Ruby Class or Module name?
More generally, how do I match sequences of words separated by double colons?

```
Word1::Word2
Word1::Word2::Word3
Word1::Word2::Word3::Word4
```

etc.

This is the closest thing I got, but it only works for up to two consecutive words:

`string.scan /[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\:\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`

Comment: Would you mind showing your efforts?

Comment: Sure thing, I didn't get too far though.. question edited

Comment: Just repeat second group: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\:\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` or `\b\w+(?:::\w+)+\b`

Comment: @revo that works, thank you so much! Do you care adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: coconup, in future consider waiting longer before awarding the green checkmark. Here is would have made no difference because the second answer (mine) was posted several hours after you asked the question. In general, however, quick selections can discourage other answers and some consider it discourteous to those still working on answers. The point is there is no rush. Many members wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer. My comments are general and do not reflect on the selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine you should only quantify capturing group or a shorter:

```
\b\w+(?:::\w+)+\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/xIjRBY/1)

Comment: You should require that individual class names begin with a capital letter and permit the string to begin with `"::"`. Also, are the word breaks (`\b`) necessary, considering that you are matching word characters?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure about capital letters by looking at OP's own regex, and I'm not sure about beginning optional `::` too this way. But no, word boundaries are not necessary and they can safely be removed as `\w+` is matching greedily every word character but if I use capital letters then I'm in need of them: `\b[A-Z]\w*(?:::\w+)+`

Comment: `"A::a".scan /\b[A-Z]\w*(?:::\w+)+/ #=> ["A::a"]`, which is not a valid module name. (Aside: you need to run your avatar through Photoshop.)

Comment: Thank you but you should ask OP why they weren't accurate about requirements. Sorry, it's not a case for me. If OP clear I'm open to modify my solution though. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

```
R = /
    \A         # match beginning of string
    (?:        # begin a non-capture group
      (?:::)?  # optionally match two colons
      \p{Lu}   # match an uppercase letter
      \w*      # match zero or more word characters
    )+         # close non-capture group and execute group one or more times
    \z         # match end of string
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

'AB::CD::EF'.match?(R)           #=> true
'A'.match?(R)                    #=> true
'::A::C_d::E3F_'.match?(R)       #=> true
'AB::cD::EF'.match?(R)           #=> false
'AB:::CD::EF&'.match?(R)         #=> false
```

Alternatively, we could write the following.

```
def valid_mod_name?(str)
  i = str[0,2]=='::' ? 2 : 0
  str[i..-1].split('::').all? { |s| s.match?(/\A\p{Lu}\w*\z/) }
end

valid_mod_name? 'AB::CD::EF'     #=> true
valid_mod_name? 'A'              #=> true
valid_mod_name? '::A::C_d::E3F_' #=> true
valid_mod_name? 'AB::cD::EF'     #=> false
valid_mod_name? 'AB:::CD::EF&'   #=> false
```

Comment: Why `\A` and `\z` since OP is using `scan`? and I think you are just doing `(?:(?:::)?[A-Z]\w*)+` without considering proper boundaries.

Comment: @revo, I don't know why coconup is using `scan` as there is no intent to extract the individual components of the module name, but we certainly don't want to match `"1AB::CD&"`; hence the anchors. Note that I only have `(?:::)?` for the first group matched` (to permit, for example, `"::A::B"`); the other groups require `::`.

Comment: If `::` doesn't occur it simply matches an upper case word like `A` in your examples. It doesn't differ in this regard. Both regexes match the same thing.

Comment: By `\A` you are telling match should happen right at beginning and it should end on the same line. And file or input string shouldn't have more than a module name in it. Do you think it is that what OP asks for?

Comment: @revo, your penultimate comment makes a good point. I've changed my answer accordingly. Thanks. As to your last comment, yes, I assumed that the problem is to determine if a given string represented a valid module name. If not, we'd have to deal with strings such as "AB::CD::eF". Yes, it contains a substring that represents a valid module name ("AB::CD"), but the complete string does not represent a valid module name. What are we to conclude?